# Making Input Equal to Variable

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

well this is probably something really simple, but I want may Input to be my variable and this is what I have so far... if possible how could this be done in VBscript?

```
@echo off

    set var=Input
    set /p Input=Enter model name:


    echo "%var%"

pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

    set var=Input 
    set /p %var%=Enter model name:


    call echo %%%var%%%

pause
```

?

Not sure if this what you mean.